# Will (¬) take away the ()?

Tags: logic

I have this proposition to break down :
$\neg(p\lor(q\land(\neg p\rightarrow r)))$

Will the NOT $(\neg)$ take away some of the parentheses when breaking down this proposition? or will they stay and peel off a layer at at time?

Comment: Parentheses don't really 'break down' per se; they only group terms. Whether they're even necessary or not depends on your specific precedence rules.  They're just an abstract representation of the inherent (more or less) tree nature of an expression like this.

Comment: But yes $\neg(p\vee s)$ is equivalent to $\color{silver}{(} \neg p\wedge \neg s\color{silver}{)}$, so keeping the *outermost* parenthesis after applying DeMorgan's rule is optional.  [However, the interior parenthesis will need to remain.]

Comment: So is this valid : ¬p ∧ ( q ∧ (¬ p -> r) ) ) or would DeMorgan's Law go all the way thru to get this ¬p ∧ ( ¬q v ¬(¬ p -> r) ) ).... Obviously i didn't simplify all the way just wanted to make sure that was correct @GrahamKemp

Comment: Yes, $$\neg(p\vee(q\wedge(\neg p\to r))) \\\equiv\\\neg p\wedge\neg(q\wedge(\neg p\to r))\\\equiv\\\neg p\wedge(\neg q\vee\neg(\neg p\to r))\\\equiv\\\neg p\wedge(\neg q\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg r))\\\equiv\\\vdots$$